# Postgres: Enforce group of `belongs_to` associations to have exactly one column at any given time with a value of `true`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of associations and I want to ensure that in a set there is exactly 1 occurrence of the value `true` in x column at any given time.

For example.

If `Business` has_many `Contacts` with a boolean column called `is_primary'

and I have 3 contacts that share a `business_id`...

How do I assure that the data never exists in a state other than where exactly one of those 3 contacts have an `is_primary` value of `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

```
create unique index unq_business_contact
    on business(contact)
    where is_primary;
```